# juice:dialog gives "Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter"

Tags: jquery, juice-ui

I'm trying to get the modal dialog to work. I'm using JuiceUI in a Web Form.
In my master page's head, I have this code:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
```

In the content of the aspx page linked to the master page, I have this div

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" runat="server">
<div id="_Default" class="basic-dialog" title="Basic dialog" runat="server">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information.</p>
</div>
<juice:dialog TargetControlID="_Default" AutoOpen="false" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

It seems like I'm missing something to get the juice:dialog working.

Any idea?